# Having variables in Blaze Template for Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

From the Template.helper in Meteor JS I get an array which I can use by

```
{{#each array_result}}
  {{value}}
{{/each}}
```

What I want is

```
<table>
  {{#each array_result}}
    {{if count%4 ===0}}</tr><tr>
      <td>{{value}}</td>
      {{count++}}
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your array in your helper and mark each 4th item in some special way before returning the result to the template:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  array_result: function() {
    // fetch an array of docs/items somehow
    var docs = SomeCollection.find().fetch();

    // iterate over them and mark each 4th item as "awesome"
    _.each(docs, function(doc, index) {
      if (index % 4 === 0)
        doc.isAwesome = true;
    });

    // return the modified documents
    return docs;
  }
});
```

Your template could then look something like this:

```html
<table>
  {{#each array_result}}
    {{#if isAwesome}}
      ...
    {{else}}
      ...
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @David.

I believe one should use Grids with CSS which has overflow feature and are responsive than HTML tables.